# How to randomly selecet a file from folder rename it and copy it to a new folder

Tags: shell, xargs

I am trying to randomly selected a file from a folder rename it using today's date and copy it to another folder. Based on other approaches using find & shuf I can select a random file and copy it to the directory using:

```
find ~/perf-test-files/tnp -type f -print0 | xargs -0 shuf -e -n 1 -z | xargs -0 cp -vt /app/staging
```

Using sed in another approach I can copy all files a rename the using current date.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt'| sed 's/\.txt$//' | xargs -I{} cp {}.txt /app/staging/{}.$(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S').txt
```

Unfortunately I cannot seem to combine this two get my required result.The below script returns
xxxx.txt.20210222143153.txt instead of **xxxx.20210222143153.txt**

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' -print0 | xargs -0 shuf -e -n 1 -z | sed 's/\.txt$//' | xargs -0  -I{} cp {} /app/staging/{}.$(date '+%Y%m%d%H%M%S').txt
```

Comment: `xargs shuf` you  are shuffling file __contents__? Is your intentation to shuffe file __names__? If so - drop the `xargs`.

Comment: `find ~/perf-test-files/tnp -type f -print0 | xargs -0 shuf -e -n 1 -z` Does this not return a single random filename from the folder? I want to selectone and then copy it with a modified name. I think my sed command is not working...

Comment: `xargs -0` Passes the filenames to `shuf`, and then `shuf` will read from file content and output one line from the files content.